# setting edit text visible each time button is pressed

Tags: android

Actually I want that each time I press the button 2 edit text is set visible,and same thing should happen each time the button is pressed.
Basically whenever user presses the button 2 edittext should appear(any loop concept?)
Please suggest.ThankYou :)

Comment: and when should it disappear?

Comment: It should remain visible after the button is pressed.Initially it is in the gone state.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a click listener to the button, and change the visibility of editText into it :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        editTextName.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, according to your code this will happen Only once i.e when the button is pressed the first time. I want that each time the button is pressed this thing happens.i.e whenever user presses the button 2 editText pops up(set visible)

Comment: i'm not sure i understand. The edit text has to disappear when I release the button ?

Comment: No, what should happen is whenever the button is pressed 2 edit Text should appear and they should remain there thereafter.

Comment: If they never disappear, which effect do you excpect after the first time?

Comment: See, initially they are in "gone" state. whenever the button is pressed two of the EditText is set 'visible' and this should happen each time the button is pressed

Comment: This happen each time you press the button, but if you don't make them disappear elsewhere, you don't see any effect, but the action "setVisible(true)" is performed every time you click the button

Comment: See,  what I mean is Every time button is pressed 2 new editText appears or are set visible for the user to enter.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i got your question right but you can use `android:setvisibility=gone` in xml editext fields and then in your button onclick use

```
edittext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

to make the edittext fields visible.

Comment: Well initially the editText is in gone state. and each time button is pressed 2 editText is set visible.According to your code it will happen only for the first time when the button is pressed. I want that to happen multiple times i.e whenever button is pressed edit text should be set visible

Answer (score 0):

Just set the initial visibility in the code or in the xml to GONE 
and then add onClickListener

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

//or

```
btn2.setVisibility(View.GONE)

btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
e@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    editText.setVisible(true);
   }
});
```

Comment: How to do this multiple times (Any loop concept)?  I want that each time button is pressed edit Text should be set visible

Comment: In order for edit text to be visible each time button is pressed it should be invisible some time .. where are u setting the invisibility ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to populate an edittext each time a button is pressed ?

Create a layout for your edittext:

```
    public EditText createEditText() { 
    final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
    final EditText edittext = new EditText(this); Editext.setLayoutParams(lparams);
 return edittext; }
```

And then add edittexts to your layout:

```
rl.addView(createEditText());
```

Comment: yes, each time button is pressed 2 edit text should appear

Comment: First of all Thankyou. And what should be done to pass the information entered by user to another activity by each of the editText created.I mean how to use "Intent_obj.putExtra()" here for these dyanamically created editText, or is there a different way to do it.? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to set edit text to visible on the press of a button. This can be done by following steps:

In your Main Class:

Create 2 new `EditText` variable:

```
EditText myEditText1;
EditText myEditText2;
```

Create a new method to be called on button click:

```
void buttonClick(View view){

       //Get References
       myEditText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.first_edit_text);
       myEditText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.second_edit_text);

       //Set visible
       myEditText1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       myEditText2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

       //Set edit texts to empty string to reset ("Recreation")
       myEditText1.setText("");
       myEditText2.setText("");
   }
```

In your xml:

Add the `onClick` attribute to your Button:

```
android:onClick="buttonClick";
```

Add the `id` to your EditTexts:

```
android:id="@+id/first_edit_text"
android:id="@+id/second_edit_text"
```

Now, Whenever the button is pressed, the Edit Text becomes visible, no loop is required. And if you also want to be hidden before pressing button, add:

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

Sources: [setVisibility](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)), [onClick](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)

Comment: But, this should happen each time button is pressed.According to your code this will happen only once,i.e the first time button is pressed.

Comment: Do you want a new edit text to appear every time the button is pressed? Could you describe the desired behavior step by step?

Comment: Yes, each time the button is pressed 2 edit text appears

Comment: I take it that you want to give impression of recreation of edittexts. This can be done by using `setText("")` so that they are reset (As done in edit, see answer). Another alternative would be to set them to Invisible, and then visible (Maybe including a time delay in between?)